# Procedure in MySQL phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I want to make a page view counter in ASP and want check if 10 minutes have passed since last view from some ip. I hve written a procedure in MySQL phpmyadmin that checks that in database.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE counter(
    in  ipOfVisitor varchar(30), 
    in  pid  int(10))
BEGIN


    SELECT @visitor_IP := ip, @date_dif := DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , last_counted )
    FROM visitors
    WHERE ip = ipOfVisitor ;

    IF (NOT @visitor_IP = null AND @date_dif > 600) OR @visitor_IP = null THEN
    UPDATE patientifo SET numberofclicks = numberofclicks + 1 WHERE id = pid;
    END IF;
    IF NOT @visitor_IP = null AND @date_dif > 600 THEN
    UPDATE visitors SET last_counted = CURDATE( ) where ip = ipOfVisitor;
    END IF;
    IF @visitor_IP = null THEN
    INSERT INTO visitors (ip, last_counted) VALUES (ipOfVisitor, CURDATE ());
    END IF;
END
```

But it gives error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE counter( IN ipOfVisitor VARCHAR( 30 ) , IN pid INT( 10 ) ) BEGIN SELECT @visitor_IP := ip, @date_dif := DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , last_counted ) 
FROM visitors
WHERE ip = ipOfVisitor;
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

What does it mean?

**EDIT**

I changed the code like [juergen d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575376/juergen-d) has said.

```
 DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE counter(
    in  ipOfVisitor varchar(30), 
    in  pid  int(10))
BEGIN
    DECLARE visitor_IP varchar(30);
    DECLARE date_dif int(10);

    SELECT ip,DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , last_counted ) INTO visitor_IP,  date_dif
    FROM visitors
    WHERE ip = ipOfVisitor ;

    IF (NOT visitor_IP = null AND date_dif > 600) OR visitor_IP = null THEN
    UPDATE patientifo SET numberofclicks = numberofclicks + 1 WHERE id = pid;
    END IF;
    IF NOT visitor_IP = null AND date_dif > 600 THEN
    UPDATE visitors SET last_counted = CURDATE( ) where ip = ipOfVisitor;
    END IF;
    IF visitor_IP = null THEN
    INSERT INTO visitors (ip, last_counted) VALUES (ipOfVisitor, CURDATE ());
    END IF;
END
|
```

And it almost works. Except this error at the last line:
 `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '|' at line 22`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter. Otherwise the DB thinks your procedure definition ends at the first `;` which would be incomplete.

```
delimiter |
CREATE PROCEDURE counter(
    in  ipOfVisitor varchar(30), 
    in  pid  int(10))
BEGIN    
   ...
END
|
```

Comment: it almost works, however it gives error at last line

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '|' at line 22

Comment: There seems to be something wrong. What code did you execute?

Comment: Actually it works for me. I executed the exact code you provided